# Laravel Eloquent - method to obtain grandchildren's data from GrandParents

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm making Ecommerce-website and I have the following relationship:

**Grandparents** : Category ( id , name ) 
**Parents** : Brand ( id , name , category_id ) 
**Children** : Product  ( id , name , brand_id )

Example :
Smartphone *(Category)* -> iPhone *(Brand)* -> iPhone 12, iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 12 Pro Max *(Product)* 
I want to get all the iPhone 12 as above from Category likes

`$iPhone = App\Category::find(1)->brands->where('name','iPhone')->toArray()`

Thanks for helping

Comment: use the hasManythrough relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO get all products from brand 'iPhone' for category 'Smartphone'

```php
$iphones = Category::whereName('Smartphone')
    ->with(['brands' => function($query){
        $query->with('products')->whereName('iPhone');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 $iPhones = App\Category::whereHas('brands', function ($query)
        {
            $query->where('name','iPhone');
        })->get();
```